# How to add Material Icon To Angular Data Table Headers

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, material-design

I'm trying to add a icon to to the table header of an Angular Data Table. What am I missing?

Also, I want to make this clickable in order to show a modal. What should I add?

`````
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Action Name </th>
<mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon"></mat-icon>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let action"> {{action.actionName}} </td>
        </ng-container>````
`````

Comment: What do you want to be clickable, the cell or the header?

Comment: @t8tortotlover the header to be clickable that would open a modal box.

Comment: So basically when I click the table header, I should be able to see a modal box that eventually i will build a filter function in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the icon component within the header:

```html
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>
  <mat-icon svgIcon="thumbs-up" aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example thumbs up SVG icon"></mat-icon>
  Action Name
</th>
<td mat-cell *matCellDef="let action"> {{action.actionName}} </td>
```